# Understating the acceleration equation in terms of velocity

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Sorry if this is considered a ‘basic’ question, but I’ve been stuck on this for a while now and can’t find much help. I know $\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{1}{2} v^2\right) =$ acceleration. But I do not understand what is wrong with my working out.

$$\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) = \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) = \frac{d}{dx} (v^2)$$ I don’t know why I am missing the half that is in the original equation. I have seen the proof for it, but I do not exactly know what wrong assumption I am making. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your working should go like this:

$a = \frac{dv}{dt}= \frac{dv}{dx} \cdot \frac {dx} {dt} = v\frac{dv} {dx}$

and at this point observe that $d(v^2) = 2vdv$, which allows you to rewrite the final expression as:

$ \frac{d(\frac 12 v^2)}{dx}$ as required.

Your error was in thinking $\frac {d}{dx} (\frac{dx} {dt})$ is a multiplication. It is not. It is differentiation of the velocity with respect to the displacement.

Comment: Minor comment: since we are talking about chain rules, it is probably important to keep distinction between partial and full derivatives. As such, the first line you wrote only holds if $v$ is explicitly independent of time, thus if it only depends on time implicitly via $x$

Comment: So just to clarify, does chain rule not work with the ‘verb’ d/dx? It only works for derivatives dy/dx? Thanks again

Comment: @Deepak Actually, I'm wrong. It somehow holds even in the case with explicit dependence

Comment: @Subbota It works fine. For instance $\frac{d}{dx} z = \frac{d}{dy} z \cdot \frac{dy} {dx} $. You just have to be careful how you apply, write and interpret it.

Comment: Ohhh I see now what you meant by me treating it as a multiplication. It makes so much sense now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Deepak's answer, the result he quotes in the first line actually holds for total derivatives as well. Perhaps this proof is useful to the OP

$$\frac{d v(x, t)}{dt}
= \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt}
= \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} v $$

$$\frac{d v(x, t)}{dx}
= \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} \frac{dt}{dx}
= \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} \frac{1}{v} $$

Multiplying lower equation by $v$ and subtracting the two yields

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = v \frac{dv}{dx}$$

Comment: That’s interesting, I haven’t learnt it that way before. It is really clear as well.

Comment: @Subbota you will eventually. As soon as you do any thermodynamics, fluid dynamics, etc these derivatives are everywhere